# How to get systemtimestamp in Cassandra

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra

How will i get `systemtimestamp` from cassandra-cli like `select sysdate from dual;` in oracle.
i am using cassandra in windows7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this makes sense for Cassandra. Each Cassandra node has its own system clock - these are distributed and independent so there is no inherent "system" time as such - but, the nodes and clients must be synchronized using NTP or similar, otherwise you may get out-of-order updates i.e. data corruption.

When making updates, the client's timestamp is used, not the server's (again, NTP sync needed). See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel

So the shared NTP clock is the only meaningful system time.